# How do I use csv.DictReader to get my csv data?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, generator

I have this piece of code

```
def reader(file='file.csv', fields=['user','email', 'fname', 'lname', 'pass']):
   with open (file) as f:
       f_reader= csv.DictReader(f, fields)
       yield f_reader
```

However, to actually use this function in my code, I have to do this:

```
eggs= reader()
for spam in eggs:
    for row in spam:
        print(row['email'])
```

That is, a generator is created inside a generator. What I want is that I get to access my csv data using just a single `for` loop. How do I do that?
Also, if I replace `yield` with `return`, I get an `IOError: operation on closed file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be quite simple:

```
def reader(file='file.csv', fields=['user','email', 'fname', 'lname', 'pass']):
with open (file) as f:
   f_reader= csv.DictReader(f, fields)
   yield from f_reader # <---Change here
```